# undefined unable to resolve module react-navigation-stack from app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I installed react-navigation and all its dependencies step by step based on its documentation.
I've created two components in a single file named`root.js`  this is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,


} from 'react-native';


import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

This is the first competent:

```
const Homescreen = () => {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Home screen</Text>
            <Button
                title='go to next page'


            ></Button>

        </View>


    )}
```

Second one:

```
const Loginscreen = () => {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Login screen</Text>
            <Button
                title='go back'


            ></Button>

        </View>


    )}
```

This the navigation code:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({

    Home: { screen: Homescreen },
    Login: { screen: Loginscreen }

},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home'

    }


);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Then i imported `AppNavigator` into `App.js` file like this:

```
import AppNavigator from './src/root';

const App=() =>  {


  return (

    <View style={styles.container} >


< AppNavigator/>

    </View>



  )
};
```

react native version is:  "0.61.5".

react-navigation version is: "^4.1.1".

And all dependencies have been installed.

I am getting following error, Which part did i make mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible the install failed for react-navigation-stack. Try installing it again and if you are using npm or yarn as your package manage, look for confirmation in the file package.json.

```
npm install react-navigation-stack
```

Comment: You saved my time, I really appreciate it, Issue was solved.